# Will this work? Adding an alias domain and moving primary domain MX to M365

Tags: email, microsoft-office-365, mx-record, g-suite

We have a special extenuating situation. We have a business we've had for 20 years using example1.com and we're being forced by our contract to switch and use M365 encrypted email but the entire business runs on Google Workspace. My idea is to buy a second domain example.com and add it as an alias in workspace with the MX records connected to Google and switching the primary domain MX to M365. So all future email is handled on M365 but users can still login to Workspace using @example1.com and still use all Google for our business as we have for 10 years.

1. The question is, will this work? I have apprehensions that some purchased add-ons, like Form Publisher may break on things like their workflows with email notifications. And GCPW is used on computers.
2. Will we still receive notifications on M365 for Google doc approval requests using Google workspace?
3. Will comment notifications still be sent to users on the M365 email?
4. Does GmailApp.sendEmail still allow you to change sender to your alias domain instead of primary?

Comment: WTF is "M365 encrypted email" ? The only thing Google seems to know about this is a small UK Office 365 mail admin service. I am not aware of Microsoft offering any sort of email encryption capability not available on multiple other platforms.

Comment: @symcbean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/what-is-information-protection

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to verify the domain in M365. And an MX nowadays is not enough you also need SPF and DMARC. Owh yeah please clarity what M365 encrypted email exactly is being used? Secure/Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (S/MIME) or `Microsoft Purview Message Encryption` or IRM?

Comment: @vidarlo AIP is about labelling and encryption at rest

Comment: @symcbean and DRM on e-mails.

Comment: It's Microsoft Purview Message Encryption (required AIP). S/Mime doesn't work for Healthcare customers who don't know what pgp/gpg Keys are or how to use them, though neither does the government letters org that runs our oversight.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [Change your primary domain for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7009324?hl=en) instead of adding an alias. That would make more sense, if the mail is not handled by Google Workspace anymore.

Instead of buying a new domain, I would recommend using a subdomain like `gws.example.com`.

Comment: That wouldn't allow email though would it? The MX is changing to M365. Some Google projects we use GmailApp.sendEmail for notifications, meaning they wouldn't be able to send emails right? We have a bot account that runs though programs to send the emails and they always come from the bot email address when sent to employees.

Comment: Whatever domain you configure for Google Workspace, you'll use that for the sender.